# Nginx location return 404 for vue js app with path param

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I am bit confuse about Nginx and vue js router.

I have the following uri:

1. / -> home page
2. /ads -> display a list
3. /ad -> create form
4. /add/:id -> dispaly an ad in full view

Runing the app whitout nginx is working fine for all uri.

Now working with nginx and docker compose I only get the 3 first but the last one give me a 404 and I do not get why.

Here the nginx conf:

```
events { }

    http {
    
      map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
          default upgrade;
          ''      close;
        }
    
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        return 301 https://localhost$request_uri;
             }
    
       server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
    
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/key.pem;
    
        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stderr warn;
    
        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
                proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
           }
    
        location /ads {
              include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
              proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
          }
    
          location /ad {
              include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
              proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
          }
    
    
        location /back {
           rewrite ^/back(.*)$ $1 break;
           include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
           proxy_pass http://backend:8081/;
        }
    
       }
    }
```

And the vue js router:

```
// Composables
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('@/layouts/default/Default.vue'),
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            name: 'Home',
            // route level code-splitting
            // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
            // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '@/views/Home.vue'),
        },
        {
            path: 'ads',
            name: 'Advertisements',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '@/views/AdsList.vue'),
        },
        {
            path: 'ad/:id',
            name: 'AdvertisementView',
            component: () => import(`@/views/AdFullView.vue`),
        }
        ,
        {
            path: 'ad',
            name: 'CreateAdvertisementView',
            component: () => import(`@/views/CreateAd.vue`),
        }
    ],
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
})

export default router
```

EDIT:

I tried to remove the location /ads and /add and I got:
It was not working any more I got this from docker compose:

docker_frontend_1: [2023-08-12T15:05:10.033Z]  "GET /ads" Error (404): "Not found"

And from nginx: 2023-08-12T15:05:10.034287711Z 172.19.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2023:15:05:10 +0000] "GET /ads HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0"

So perhaps something is missconfigured somewhere else.

EDIT 2:

I checked my front end container alone and I also got a 404.

My docker file look like this:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app
# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./
# install project dependencies (before copying sources to take advantage of docker cached layers)
RUN npm install
# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .
# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as production-stage
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app/dist
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

When trying to reach /ads directly from the URL I got: 2023-08-13T10:11:45.825736885Z [2023-08-13T10:11:45.825Z]  "GET /ads" Error (404): "Not found"

I am guessing the node server is badly configured.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the 4th path is not `/add/$id` instead `/ad/:id`:

```js
        {
            path: 'ad/:id',
            name: 'AdvertisementView',
            component: () => import(`@/views/AdFullView.vue`),
        },
```

Also in your nginx configuration you have the following:

```
        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
                proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
           }
    
        location /ads {   # block can be deleted
              include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
              proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
          }
    
          location /ad {   # block can be deleted
              include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
              proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
          }
```

You should be able to delete those 2 blocks safely, because the first location block is including both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `vue-cli` ? If yes then, you can follow the official `vue-cli` docs about deploying vue app with nginx and docker [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx).

Here's the official `vue-cli` guide for `nginx`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: I'll show you the `Dockerfile` configuration:

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

As you can see, the `nginx` file is inside the container lifecycle, it's not the part of your hosted computer nginx configuration

Comment: I used vutified but I can check, thx.

Comment: I checked the conf but my nginx is in front of multiple docker container so I do not want it to be linked to vue app.

Comment: Well, that nginx configuration is part of the docker container itself. So it's linked to each of your vue container. After that, you can use nginx on your hosted computer for each of your container. I've edited my answer to show you the dockerfile configuration